# Capturing an error in a Javascript subfile loaded through dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, syntax-error

I have jQuery and a main Javascript file as part of the document, which includes code like this:

```
try{
  $(document.body).append('<script src=\"path_to_a_sub_javascript_file\"></script>');
} catch(error){
  alert('something wrong with the file');
};
```

This is intended to load a Javascript subfile and catch any error in it if there is any. When the subfile has no errors, it is loaded correctly. When the subfile has a load-time error (syntax error, or error in part of code that is immediately run), I want to capture the error with `try` `catch` construction, but it is not caught.

How can I make an error in the subfile be caught by the code in the main file that loads it?

Comment: pretty sure jQuery does not throw exceptions.

Comment: @RPM Using jQuery's `append` is not a neccesity. Is there a pure JavaScript way?

Comment: Are you talking about just a loading error, or ALL possible errors in every piece of code in the path_to_a_sub_javascript_file?

Comment: @RPM I wrote above, all errors that occur while **reading** the file, such as **syntax error, or error in part of code that is immediately run**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery's getScript method

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
 .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
   console.log( textStatus );
 })
 .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
  // error
});
```

if there is any error in loaded javascript fail method will be called

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. When I have a global object defined in the global name space in some subfile and try to refer to that object in another subfile, it is not recognized.

Comment: @sawa see this http://plnkr.co/edit/CTJ315SvddqXjdniuOhe everything is working fine. global variable remain global in this approach.

Comment: I saw your demo. There is no global variable defined in your subfile `script.js`. Furthermore, you only have one subfile `script.js`.

Comment: yes in it there is a global variabe "a", after loading i am using this global variable in index file see "setTimeout"

Comment: After reading about `getScript`, I found that it might be the case that loading is done asynchronously, so it is not guaranteed that one is read after the previous one is completely loaded. In your edited code, is it guaranteed that loading `script.js` is completed before `script2.js` is read? Particularly, if you put more stuff before definition of `a` in `script.js`, couldn't it happen that `a` in `script2.js` be attempted to be referred to before the initialization in `script.js`?

Comment: you are right these request are async but you can make them sync using $.ajaxSetup({async:false});